# Add content to second page with mpdf

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf

I'm using https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf to create PDFs in Yii2. I have my first page, but I need to add a page break and make sure that I start the second piece of information on a fresh page. I'm unsure how to do this. I have tried:

```
    public function actionReports()
{
  $data = date('d F Y',time());
  $content = $this->renderPartial('_billing', [
    'model' => $data,
  ]);

  $doc = new Pdf([
    // set to use core fonts only
    'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
    // A4 paper format
    'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
    // portrait orientation
    'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
    // stream to browser inline
    'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
    // your html content input
    'content' => $content,
  ]);

  return $doc->render();
}
```

**View**

```
use yii\helpers\Html;

?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 text-center">
  <?= Html::img(\Yii::getAlias('@web') .  '/images/c.png'); ?>
  <?= Html::img(\Yii::getAlias('@web') .  '/images/s.png', ['width' => 150, 'height' => 55]); ?>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12  margin-add">
<h4 class="text-center text-gray">Quarterly Billing Summary</h4>

<p><?= $model; ?></p>
....
rest of text
....
<pagebreak/>
...
Tabulated report of billing
...
```

The `<pagebreak/>` doesn't seem to render a 2nd page?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try simply creating a view with both page and adding

```
"<pagebreak/>" in view where you need this will create page break
```

is more simple respect to manage two page..

This is from http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=108

You can force a page break anywhere in the document either by using HTML code or PHP:

```
$mpdf->AddPage();

<pagebreak />
```

Comment: Just tried it, and the text continued on the first page

Comment: Using chrome...Same result in Firefox though

Comment: I have slightly update the answer.. evntually show your related view (part of)

Comment: My pagebreak was wrong, I missed the space out `<pagebreak />`

Answer (score 3):

```
$invoice_nos = ['0' => $html, '1' => $html, '2' => $html];

$this->mpdf= new mPDF('TH','A4');
$this->mpdf->defaultheaderfontsize=12;
$this->mpdf->defaultheaderfontstyle='B';
$this->mpdf->defaultheaderline=0;
$this->mpdf->setFooter($footer);
$this->mpdf->SetHeader('Bill | | <strong>Pages {PAGENO} of {nb}</strong>');

foreach ($invoice_nos as $key => $invoice_no) {

 $this->mpdf->AddPage();
 $this->mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
}

$this->mpdf->defaultfooterline=0;
$this->mpdf->Output();
$this->mpdf->Output('.date('Y-m-d').'.pdf','F');
```